# Indexed objects: Should it be "case 1 or 2" or "cases 1 or 2"?

Tags: grammatical-number

When one refers to more than one **indexed** objects, should the leading noun (that is applied to every one of the objects) be singular or plural?

For example, *which is correct?*

1. Case**s** 1 or 2
2. Case 1 or 2

Note that in 1 "cases" is plural" and in 2 "case" is singular. The intended meaning is "case 1 or case 2" - any of the two cases.

(One may replace "case" with "theorem", "lemma", "assumption", etc., or "lot", "room", "level", "unit" ...)

*What principle do we invoke here?*

Note: The question is about the consistency between noun and index, not subject-verb agreement. In fact, the phrase here *does not necessarily serve as the subject* in a sentence; it can equally serve as the object or another part of speech. When it does serve as the subject, then the verb must agree with the form of noun chosen for it.

Comment: “Or” normally resolves to a single item (any one of them).

Comment: @Lawrence Does it mean only "Case 1 or 2 holds" is correct? Is there a source that I can cite for this rule?

Comment: It’s hard to say without further context, but typically you’d expect singular agreement (more accurately, agreement with *each* of the items). For sources on basic grammar, [ell.se] might be able to help you. I’d also expect basic grammar books to have this information.

Comment: @Lawrence All the grammar books I've seen focus on the agreement between noun and verb, which isn't helpful here. I have yet to see a discussion about indexed nouns so that more than one object can share a single leading noun, and what form should this noun take. I will also post the question to ELL.SE.

Comment: [UK government](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2022/117/regulation/14/made) says "case 1 or 2". Googling and reading through the results.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Exclusive vs. inclusive OR**
"Any" does not clearly express if both may be valid at the same time.
N.B. My job includes reading and writing technical documentation. There, if **either** case 1 **or** case 2 may apply, exclusively, singular is required. On the other hand, if at least in some instances **both** case 1 and case 2 could satisfy some condition, using plural indicates this opportunity.
So, while singular is the most common solution, sometimes plural may be used to help understanding.

Comment: So the suggestion is to use "case 1 or 2" if only one of the two may be true and use "cases 1 or 2" if both can be true simultaneously?

Comment: Yes, use "cases 1 or 2" if one or both must be true, like you use "cases 1 and 2"  if both must  apply together.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a source that I can cite for this?

Comment: It's a pity that no reputable source has been added and yet the answer has been accepted. I find 'Theorems 1 or 2 are often used in further proofs' unacceptable. I'd use 'Theorems 1 and 2 (sometimes in tandem) are often used in further proofs'

Answer (score 0):

Case 1 or 2 means either case 1 or case 2, so there is only one case each time. Cases 1 or 2 do not make sense. Cases 1 and 2 would be correct because there are two cases.